# Button text blurring when hovering over an icon

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I've made the icon of the paper plan shake when hovered over. However, the text on the buttons underneath blurs a bit too. I tried removing the animation and the text still blurs when you hover over the icon (despite the icon not doing anything).

CSS for the animation:

```
.fa-shake {
  animation: shake 0.82s cubic-bezier(.36,.07,.19,.97) both;
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  perspective: 1000px;
}

@keyframes shake {
  10%, 90% {
    transform: translate3d(-1px, 0, 0);
  }

  20%, 80% {
    transform: translate3d(2px, 0, 0);
  }

  30%, 50%, 70% {
    transform: translate3d(-4px, 0, 0);
  }

  40%, 60% {
    transform: translate3d(4px, 0, 0);
  }
}
```

jQuery:

```
$('.plane').hover(function() {
    $(this).addClass('fa-shake');
}, function () {
    $(this).removeClass('fa-shake');
});
```

[Full code](http://codepen.io/l-emi/pen/kXdXXR) if needed.

Answer (score 3):

I'd be adding the the shake to the icon..not the whole div.

```
$('.plane').hover(function() {
    $(this).find('i').addClass('fa-shake');
}, function () {
    $(this).find('i').removeClass('fa-shake');
});
```

This seems to fix the problem - [**Codepen**](http://codepen.io/l-emi/pen/kXdXXR)

Comment: Its still there for me in chrome.